# How to create a horizontally scrolling div with multiple divs inside

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a horizontally scrolling parent div with 4 other child divs inside it. after attempting this I've got stuck on a problem, the parent div gives me a scroll bar that is too big to go through all 4 of the smaller child divs. then it gives me a second scroll bar at the bottom of the page allowing me to scroll over fully but doing this moves the entire page not just the parent div.

see code here https://jsfiddle.net/callum2321/8jq4bmxk/

```
slider {
    top: 250px;
    width: 400%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-height: 80%;
}

box {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 3% 3%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 450px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.box:hover {
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 14px 14px darkred;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.col-1 {max-width: 100%; max-height: 45%; background-color: 
purple;}
.col-2 {width: 100%; height: 55%; background-color: purple;}

#boxA-pic {
    max-height: 40%;
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

#boxA-info {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#boxA-info h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

#boxA-info p {
    white-space: normal;
}

#boxB-pic {
    max-height: 40%;
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: fill;
}

#boxB-info {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#boxB-info h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

#boxB-info p {
    white-space: normal;
}

#boxC-pic img{
    max-height: 40%;
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: fill;
}

#boxC-info {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#boxC-info h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

#boxC-info p {
    white-space: normal;
}

#boxD-pic img {
    max-height: 40%;
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: fill;
}

#boxD-info {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#boxD-info h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

#boxD-info p {
    white-space: normal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is more or less easy to code with flexbox:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .flex-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      background-color: DodgerBlue;
    }
    
    .flex-container > div {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      margin: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 75px;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Flexible Boxes</h1>
    
    <div class="flex-container" style="overflow: auto;">
      <div>AAAAA</div>
      <div>BBBBB</div>
      <div>CCCCC</div>  
      <div>DDDDD</div>
      <div>EEEEE</div>
      <div>FFFFF</div>  
      <div>GGGGG</div>
      <div>HHHHH</div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created this super simple approach here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <style>
        .scroll {
          overflow-x: auto;
        }
        .scroll__container {
          display: -webkit-flex;
          display: -ms-flexbox;
          display: flex;
        }
        .scroll__box {
          min-width: 90%;
          margin-right: 2%;
          margin-bottom: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <section class="scroll">
    <div class="scroll__container">
      <div class="scroll__box">
         <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Numquam aliquam possimus laudantium delectus similique velit facere temporibus, nisi praesentium veniam!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="scroll__box">
         <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Numquam aliquam possimus laudantium delectus similique velit facere temporibus, nisi praesentium veniam!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="scroll__box">
         <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Numquam aliquam possimus laudantium delectus similique velit facere temporibus, nisi praesentium veniam!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="scroll__box">
         <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Numquam aliquam possimus laudantium delectus similique velit facere temporibus, nisi praesentium veniam!</p>
      </div>
    </div>

</section>
</body>
</html>


[Codepen reference](https://codepen.io/proochster/pen/RzgPNQ?editors=1100)
```

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO. Either form an answer here or delete this altogether: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23353032)

Comment: Thanks for the constructive comment @M. R. I've updated the answer.